# What can someone do to my computer with access to the modem?

Tags: network

I had to give my new neighbor my WiFi password. He's now connected to my internet and I worried about some things:

1. The modem is connected to my PC. What can he possibly do while he's on my internet?
2. I can see his MAC Address through the modem's website, what can someone do with a MAC address?
3. 5 minutes after giving him the password, the modem restarted itself. (Doesn't happen usually).

Comment: I would change the default password for the modem's website.

Comment: people still use modems? (dial up?)

Answer (score 3):

> 1. The Modem is connected to my PC. What can he possibly do while he's on my internet?

This is a very subjective question because it depends on some many things, but permit to build two scenarios.

- **Best case:** He checks his e-mails, read his favourite newspaper and nothing happens to you from a security perspective.
- **Worst case:** He has thousand of back doors and worms in his computer and this can spread to your network; his computer is a zombie which launches attacks to targets all over the world; he downloads copyrighted stuff and you will be in trouble; he is a hacker and will eavesdrop and steal your information.

> I can see his MAC Address through the modem's website, what can someone do with a MAC address?

Not much to be honest. Maybe the MAC Address you see is spoofed and not his real one. MAC can be faked so it is not the best way to precisely identify someone.

> 5 minutes after giving him the password, the modem restarted itself. (Doesn't happen usually).

It could be a coincidence but could also be that he made administrative changes to the device taking over the control (In case he could brute force the password or if you had standard credentials). Some of those changes requires the device to be restarted.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, he can TRY to attack you. This is usually worse than it sounds. Basically, he has the opportunity to exploit any outdated software, weak passwords (or default passwords - not many people change the password on their router), or bad ideas you might have. By default, your modem stops people outside your LAN from trying to do most of that (except for some outdated software, like Java). If you can't access your router/modem, he probably took control of it. Just hit the reset button and set a new password. I don't know your situation, but it would be simplest to just change your network password to kick him off. If you can't kick him off your network, you'll have to just set a nice, secure password for your router and consider putting him in a [DMZ](http://www.tp-link.us/FAQ-28.html), which should stop him from launching attacks against your computer (unless he regains access to your router).